# Given N find x and y such that N ⩽ x*y ⩽ N+2 and |x-y| is minimal

Tags: algorithm

Find the algorithm to calculate the dimensions `x` and `y` of a rectangle with a given area `N`, such that `N ⩽ x*y ⩽ N+2` and also `x` and `y` are close to form a square.

Some examples:

- `N = 100`
  Find `x` and `y` such that `100 ⩽ x*y ⩽ 102`
  and also the difference between `x` and `y` is minimal
  ⟹
  `x = 10` and `y = 10`
- `N = 99`
  `x = 10` and `y = 10`, as `100 ⩽ x*y ⩽ 102` and `x-y = 0`;
- `N = 19`
  `x = 5` and `y = 4`, as `19 ⩽ x*y ⩽ 21` and `x-y = 1`;

My answer:

1. First check if `N`, `N+1` or `N+2` are perfect squares. If 
   any is then `x = y` are its square root.
2. Otherwise, find square root of `N` and 
   `x = y = sqrt(N)`.
   Now increase `x` or `y` by 1 and check if `N ⩽ x*y ⩽ N+2` criteria is met or not.

Comment: Are all `x`, `y` and `N` integers?

Answer (score 1):

We start at the optimal real solution `x=y=sqrt(N)`. We alter this solution to the nearest integer parameterization and adapt until the condition is met. Without loss of generality, we assume that `x` is the smaller of the two values:

```
int x, y;
x = y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(N + 1));
while(x * y < N || x * y > N + 2)
{
    if (x * y > N + 2)
        --x;
    else
        ++y;
}
```

The first 20 values are:

```
N = 1: (1, 1)
N = 2: (2, 2)
N = 3: (2, 2)
N = 4: (2, 2)
N = 5: (2, 3)
N = 6: (2, 3)
N = 7: (3, 3)
N = 8: (3, 3)
N = 9: (3, 3)
N = 10: (3, 4)
N = 11: (3, 4)
N = 12: (3, 4)
N = 13: (3, 5)
N = 14: (4, 4)
N = 15: (4, 4)
N = 16: (4, 4)
N = 17: (3, 6)
N = 18: (4, 5)
N = 19: (4, 5)
N = 20: (4, 5)
```

Comment: Oh, you're right ;). Maybe, I should add that I haven't found a way to proof the algorithm's correctness. So there could be some cases I missed.

Comment: `x*y=N` describes a hyperbola in the coordinate plane, and you're walking along it looking for the first integer point that you come to.  That should prove correctness, although you'd need to think carefully about the `N`, `N+1`, `N+2` thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. set `x` and `y` to be square root of `N`
2. round `x` and `y` to the ceil, for example if `x` is 9.1 then `x` will be 10
3. `x` * `y` is always will be greater or equal to N, check if N + 2 >= `x` * `y` then you've found `x` and `y`, if not then go to 4
4. decrease the `x` by one, so the answer will be `x - 1` as `x`, and `y` as `y`

the `diff(x-y) <= 1` will be true allways

Comment: But their product may not be big enough.

Comment: Ok, understood my mistake. I'll think more.

Answer (score 0):

I assume N, x, and y must be integers. One way to solve this problem is to factor each of N, N+1, N+2, into two factors x and y such that x-y is minimized. At least one of N, N+1, N+2 is composite (if N>1) so you're guaranteed to get something better than y=1. You have to do 3*floor(sqrt(N+2)) trial divisions, though, so this algorithm isn't fast.

You want to work backwards from y=floor(sqrt(N+2)) so you can stop when you've found an answer. Once you've found an answer you might want to go one more step to see if you can find a better answer, maybe (if N is small).